# CSS keyframe animation not working

Tags: animation, css, css-transitions

I got [this animation](http://jsfiddle.net/pmfzh/1/) using keyframes that is not working in webkit or IE10 (doing those first). Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your suggestions guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about IE, but `-webkit-animate` isn't a valid property. You need to use `-webkit-animation`.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pmfzh/2/**

Answer (score 0):

Hereb is the correct CSS. Change `animate` to `animation`

```
div.run:hover{
    animation: bounce 2s;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 2s;
}
```

​